# ndk-build :- How to get the exact path from calling $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)) in windows?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, android-ndk-r5

I am doing a sample native project.
I have two make files one is Android1.mk and another one is Android2.mk.
The second one is placed outside the project folder.My android studio project is located at

> H:/Ndk_Dev/Demo

Android1.mk located at

> H:/Ndk_Dev/Demo/app/src/main/jni

and Android2.mk is located at

> H:/Ndk_Dev/externalJni

Android1.mk contains.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_ROOT_PATH := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../)
.......
.......
.......
include $(MY_ROOT_PATH)/externalJni/Android2.mk
```

but while compiling, the path i got was

```
LOCAL_PATH    -------> H:/Ndk_Dev/Demo/app/src/main/jni
MY_ROOT_PATH  -------> H:/Ndk_Dev/Demo/app/src/main/H:/Ndk_Dev
```

So it points to an invalid path for Android2.mk which was

```
H:/Ndk_Dev/Demo/app/src/main/H:/Ndk_Dev/externalJni/Android2.mk
```

On my understanding the `MY_ROOT_PATH` should be `H:/Ndk_Dev`

Have anybody know any issue in calling $(abspath) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call as following

```
MY_ROOT_PATH := $(abspath ../../../../../)
```

It works for me.